# Keras model.predict get the value for the predicion

Tags: keras

I'm new to TensorFlow and keras and I'm trying to learn with an example using this code in google's colab

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

insurance = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/insurance.csv")

#Create a column transformer
ct = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(),["age","bmi","children"]),
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"),["sex","smoker","region"])
)
X = insurance.drop("charges",axis=1)
y = insurance["charges"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#Fit the column transformer to our training data
ct.fit(X_train)

#Transform training and test data with normalization (MinMaxScaler) and OneHotEncode
X_train_normal = ct.transform(X_train)
X_test_normal = ct.transform(X_test)

insurance_model_4=tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
]
)

insurance_model_4.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['mae'])
insurance_model_4.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_train_normal, axis=-1), y_train, epochs=200)

y_preds = insurance_model_4.predict(X_test_normal)
X_test_normal.shape #this gives (268, 11)
y_preds.shape #this gives (268,11,1)
```

my issue is that I can't figure out how to get the actual values for predictions in **y_preds**, I was expecting an array with shape (268,1), that is the 268 predictions for each input in X_test_normal.¿How can I get the value of the predictions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you would need to expand the dimensions of `X_train_normal` during `.fit()`. Remove that part to simply fit on `X_train_normal`, which would give you the shape of `y_pred` as `(268, 1)` as you expected. So,

Replace:

`insurance_model_4.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_train_normal, axis=-1), y_train, epochs=200)`

with:

`insurance_model_4.fit(X_train_normal, y_train, epochs=200)`

Comment: For TensorFlow 2.7.0+ it is necessary to expand the dimensions in the .fit() otherwise it does not run. Actually, I've been able to get the correct shape in my computer, there I'm using TensorFlow 2.2, but google's colab uses TF 2.8.2

Comment: Expanding dimension refers to the idea of introducing the concept of batches into the data. If you had only one observation with 10 features you'd expand your dimension with `axis=0`, thereby changing your shape from `(10,)` to `(1, 10)`. The starting dimension in your dataset already accounts for this by having all observations batched into one. In your simple case, the dimension it expects is (batch_size, features), you're passing it as (batch_size, features, 1) hence the mismatch in shape. Code works correctly on colab after correcting it.

Comment: Now I get it, expanding is not necessary if I have more than one feature, it actually works removing the tf.expand_dims. Thanks